# oneup uploader bundle symfony : how to customize endpoint

Tags: php, symfony, upload, oneupuploaderbundle

I'm trying to customize the oneup uploader bundle "endpoint". I know I can specify the folder directly in the form like this :

```
<form action="{{ oneup_uploader_endpoint('myfolder') }}" class="dropzone">
```

But how do I change the complete path ? (I need to put it in another website on the same ftp)

(I'm using Dropzone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described [in the documentation](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#step-4-prepare-your-frontend) the `oneup_uploader_endpoint` helper returns a route where the file upload request will be sent and processed, not where the files will be stored. To change the directory you need to configure your mapping accordingly.

For example:

```
oneup_uploader:
    mappings:
        my_mapping:
            frontend: dropzone
            storage:
                directory: "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/your-folder"
```

Afterwards you can use this mapping like this:

```
{{ oneup_uploader_endpoint('my_mapping') }}
```

Comment: So it means we can not customize the end point. I want user to submit upload file request to following endpoint : /api/v1/file. Is it possible using OneUpUploaderBundle

Comment: @Tarun this is possible by adding `endpoints` parameters to the config.

`
    oneup_uploader:
        mappings:
            media:
                endpoints:
                    upload:   'filemanager/upload'
                    progress: 'filemanager/progress'
                    cancel:   'filemanager/cancel'
`